# How to hide HTML element based on Session value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to hide html element based on Session Value, using razor or js but i can't. I've tried more than one solution, but no result.

First attempt:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">الخيارات</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span> 
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li style="@(Session[" UserRole "].Equals("2 ") ? "display:none " : "display:block ")">
      <a href="@Url.Action(" ConfirmAllNotes ", "Notes ", new { ReportID = item.ReportID })"></a>اعتماد الملاحظات
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="@Url.Action(" DepartmentResponse ", "Notes ", new { ReportID =item.ReportID })">ردود الإدارة</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="@Url.Action(" Edit ", "Reports ", new {id = item.ReportID })">تعديل</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Second attempt:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">الخيارات</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    @if (Session["UserRole"].ToString().Equals("1")) {
      <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action(" ConfirmAllNotes ", "Notes ", new { ReportID = item.ReportID })"></a>اعتماد الملاحظات
      </li>
    }
    <li>
      <a href="@Url.Action(" DepartmentResponse ", "Notes ", new { ReportID =item.ReportID })">ردود الإدارة</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="@Url.Action(" Edit ", "Reports ", new {id = item.ReportID })">تعديل</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: through js not possible.

Comment: What you have should work fine. Are you sure the `Session["UserRole"]` holds the value you expect?

Comment: why not just `if(Session["UserRole"].ToString() == "1")`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes,it holds value that i need. I use it in other situation, but i'm not sure if it's the best practice.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below logic, it may work for you

```
   <li style="@(Session["UserRole"].ToString() == "2" ? "display:block" : "display:none")">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `if` instead of mixing with the element's style:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">الخيارات</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span> 
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    @if (Session[" UserRole "].Equals("2 "))
    {
    <li>
      <a href="@Url.Action(" ConfirmAllNotes ", "Notes ", new { ReportID = item.ReportID })"></a>اعتماد الملاحظات
    </li>
    }
    <li>
      <a href="@Url.Action(" DepartmentResponse ", "Notes ", new { ReportID =item.ReportID })">ردود الإدارة</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="@Url.Action(" Edit ", "Reports ", new {id = item.ReportID })">تعديل</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```